# Are answers that are commenced prior to question closure now always accepted?

Tags: support, answers, closed-questions

I had always thought that, once a question is closed, no further answers are accepted—even if those answers began to be written prior to the question's closure.  However, I've just seen [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29454835/623041) posted a whole(!) 1m28s *after* I closed its question as a dupe.

Are answers that are commenced prior to question closure now always accepted?  Or, if it is only permitted in certain cases, what are the exact rules?